# x-editable : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_off')

Tags: x-editable, conflicting-libraries

I'm using [x-editable](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable) with jqueryui library ([jqueryui-editable v1.5.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/jqueryui-editable/js/jqueryui-editable.js))

However I've suddenly got this error :

> Cannot read property '_off' of undefined

It seems the error is raised by this line :

```
this.container()._off(this.container().element, 'mouseover focusin');
```

line 4717, because `this.container()` is null.

I don't really figure out why.. ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Bootstrap` and `jqueryui-editable` conflict each other.

I've found the explanation on [the project creator's github](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/388#issuecomment-25744240)

> This problem is related with simultaneous usage of jQueryUI and Bootstrap:
> both jquery-ui and bootstrap add $.tooltip method. When used together bootstrap overwrites it and we get error.
> The solutions I can suggest:
> 1. try to include jQueryUI after bootstrap.
> 2. Better way is to use bootstrap's noConflict method. Run this after including BS :
> $.fn.bstooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();

The second solution, using `$.fn.bstooltip = $.fn.tooltip.noConflict();` worked for me.